# Why the effect size shown in the summary function and forest plot is different than TE.random in metagen when doing a meta-analysis of HR in R?

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis

I have written the following code. The output is different than the output I recieve in STATA and the pooled HR shown in the summary seems to be incorrect (larger than 1). The values stored in m.gen_bin$TE.random seem to be correct.
`m.gen_bin <- metagen(TE = HR_OS, seTE = OS_SE, studlab = study, data = data, sm = "HR", method.tau = "DL", comb.fixed = FALSE, comb.random = TRUE, overall= TRUE, title = "OS")`
Could you please kindly help me with this issue?

I tried doing the analysis with STATA as well. The study weights seem to similar with what STATA has calculated as well.

Comment: stats.stackexchange.com is a more suitable forum for this question; it's off topic here. You'll want to say more about the inputs and outputs in order to help others help you -- you'll want to post the data and the results you are getting, and say more about the discrepancy between what you expected to get, and what you actually got.